Not able to start jBPM 7.74.1.Final server with java 17 version
I have downloaded jBPM 7.74.1.Final zip file and start the server in standalone mode. I am using java 17.0.6 version. It is failing.
I tried also with java 11.0.24 version and getting the same error message. But it works for me for java 11.0.6 version.
Does jBPM 7.74.1.Final support Java 17 version?
Is there any jBPM version which supports java 17?
Any suggestion/solution for this compatibility issue?
Error log:

16:30:06,075 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-5)    ... 63 more16:30:06,075 ERROR [ErraiMarshalling] (MSC service thread 1-5) null16:30:06,075 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."business-central.war".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."business-central.war".WeldStartService: Failed to start serviceat org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1731)at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigCleanUp.postConstruct() on org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigCleanUp@70755fd1at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:38)at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:28)at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:505)at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:93)at org.jboss.as.weld@23.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:98)at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)... 6 moreCaused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigCleanUp.postConstruct() on org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigCleanUp@70755fd1at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.invokeMethods(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:85)at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.postConstruct(DefaultLifecycleCallbackInvoker.java:66)at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.postConstruct(BasicInjectionTarget.java:122)at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:174)at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.6.Final//org.jboss.weld.contexts.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)at


Is there something in logs more relevant to "Unable to invoke ..."? Ideally there should be reason why

The issue is occurring when I use java 17 version. Is jBPM 7.74.1.Final is compatible with Java 17?
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-000049: Unable to invoke public void org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigCleanUp.postConstruct() on org.guvnor.structure.backend.organizationalunit.config.SpaceConfigCleanUp@70755fd1

That version doesn't support Java 17
